# What is this shield icon doing next to meta questions?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta

Click the *Questions* tab in meta to notice a small shield next to questions. I haven't noticed this before and they don't seem to be on the main site.

[image: icons]

What are they!?

Comment: Very, very similar question [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319973/what-do-the-shield-icons-on-custom-question-list-pages-specify).

Comment: [Good question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319973/29523). They only appear on MSO and MSE, which makes me think it's related to Custom Question Lists.

Comment: Leaked in with a recent change for Teams that's currently being tested on MSE/MSO - dev is working on a fix.